# Lawtex - Como estruturar os operados lógicos em List não atomic

Tags: lawtex

```
        +<citacao> : struct[Citacao] {
            name = "Informações sobre a Citação"
            fields {
                +[passivoTentativa] : Boolean { 
                    name = "Houve a citação de todos os Executados?"
                    request = "Houve a citação de todos os Executados?"
                    default = true
                },
                if ([passivoTentativa]==false) {
                    +[passivo] : String {
                        name = "Qual(is) executado(s)(as) não foram citados?"
                        request = "Qual(is) executado(s)(as) não foram citados?"                            
                    },
                    +[passivoModalidade] : List ("Correios", "Oficial de Justiça", "Meio Eletrônico", "Carta Precatória") {
                            name = "Informar as modalidades de citação já realizadas na tentativa de Citação do(s) (as) Executados(as)"
                            request = "Informar as modalidades de citação já realizadas na tentativa de Citação do(s) (as) Executados(as)"
                            atomic = false
                    },
                    if ([passivoModalidade]=="Carta Precatória" AND ([passivoModalidade]=="Oficial de Justiça" OR "Meio Eletrônico") XOR ([passivoModalidade]=="Carta Precatória" XOR ([passivoModalidade]=="Carta Precatória") AND ([passivoModalidade]=="Carta Precatória" OR "Correios"))) {
                        +[cartaPrecatoriaCitacao] : String {
                            name = "Informe o nome do Executado, o número do processo, a Vara, a Comarca, e o TJ que tramita a Carta Precatória"
                            request = "Informe o nome do Executado, o número do processo, a Vara, a Comarca, e o TJ que tramita a Carta Precatória"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Como podem ver, especifiquei que o usuário deve informar quais foram as modalidades de tentativa de Citação dos Executados em um List não atomic. Assim quero que toda a vez que for selecionado a opção "Carta Precatória", ainda que outra opção seja selecionada também,  seja aberto o struct para informar sobre a Carta Precatória expedida para citação. Ou seja, 01 opção ou 03 opções em conjunto devem permitir o questionamento.

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1):

Para  verificar se um elemento de uma lista não-atômica foi selecionado, basta utilizar o operador IN, da seguinte forma:

```
    if("Carta Precatória" IN [passivoModalidade]) {
        +[cartaPrecatoriaCitacao] : String {
            name = "Informe o nome do Executado, o número do processo, a Vara, a Comarca, e o TJ que tramita a Carta Precatória"
            request = "Informe o nome do Executado, o número do processo, a Vara, a Comarca, e o TJ que tramita a Carta Precatória"
        }
    }
```

Dessa maneira, a condição será preenchida sempre que a Carta Precatória for selecionada, independentemente de o usuário ter marcado outras opções ou não.

Em geral, faz sentido condicionar listas atômicas com o == e listas não atômicas com o IN, já que, para listas atômicas, a opção selecionada será sempre o conteúdo inteiro da lista, que só permite uma opção.